# Why containers are not restarted?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I updated docker compose file. Then when I rebuild containers, it seems they are not restarted. Why?

Here we can see that last step is not cached and new image was created:

```
$ BUILDKIT_PROGRESS=plain docker compose --verbose -p bot -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml --env-file etc/db_env.conf up --detach --build
...
#16 [my-perl 12/12] COPY . .
#16 DONE 0.0s

#17 exporting to image
#17 exporting layers 0.0s done
DEBU[0001] stopping session                             
#17 writing image sha256:f64d73e7d5c5d5baa69df94dfc083bac08fd8395ae86e25204bad45d20007134 done
#17 naming to docker.io/library/bot_app done
#17 DONE 0.1s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Container bot-db-1   Running                                                      0.0s
 ⠿ Container bot-app-1  Running
```

Comment: Provide more information and docker logs those containers, did you docker compose down ? Or just exited the compose process?

Comment: you don't need to rebuild a container to restart it. But if you rebuild it, you need to stop previous container and run you new one. Can you share your docker-compose.yml file content?

Comment: @GuintherKovalski, No, this was the docker bug. See answer below.

Comment: @Shachar297: No, the was the docker bug. When compose was changed, containers should be restarted by `docker compose up`. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9259

This is a bug and fixed at docker compose 2.6.1. Mine version is 2.3.3